# Can I use custom criteria (from a database extension) with spring JPA specifications?

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I really found of Spring Data's JpaSpecificationExecutor, it allows me to dynamically build queries, depending on the filters applied by user.

However, I've installed a ZomboDB plugin, and now I need to support a new syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table ==> 'cats AND dogs';
```

Is it possible to extend CriteriaBuilder to use this new syntax?

Comment: What does that code mean?

Comment: @JensSchauder https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#full-text-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work.

The `JpaSpecificationExecutor` is built on JPA. But what you want to do is highly database specific.

Since ZomboDB seems to offer its own API, it is probably best to use that in a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: Do you have an example of implementing a custom method with conditional criteria?

Comment: Nope, nothing that specific.